# How to use external CSS in Material-UI instead of styling in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I started developing an application using `ReactJS` framework using `Material-UI` library. I see all styles are defined within `Javascript`, but I would like to use `CSS` to style components

How to remove the dependency on `Javascript` to style components. And is there any advantage of having styles in `JS` over `CSS`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put classes in the JavaScript code. Also, refer those classes in your desired external css file and in turn link that file on your index page.